# HTML Tag in XML`

Tags: php, html, xml

I'm having an issue with the exporting of an XML file from PHP.  It's not applying the closing tag which seems to make me end up with HTML tags

```
<!--?xml version="1.0"?-->
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
    <body>
      <entries>
        <entry>
          <img>1030.jpg
          <comment>Jean</comment>
        </entry>
      </entries>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the PHP portion creating it.

```
<?php
  include_once "config.php";
  mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd);
  mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("Cannot select db" . mysql_error());
  session_start();      
$query = "SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE state = 1 LIMIT 10";       
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<entries/>');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) { 
    $values = implode(",", $row);
    list($ep_id, $image, $origimg,  $actid , $date, $approve, $apptime, $fbid, $custid, $title, $comment, $admincom, $link, $lang, $video, $rate, $finalist, $brand, $day, $source) = explode(",", $values);
    $entry = $xml->addChild('Entry');
        $entry->addChild('link', $lang);
        $entry->addChild('comment', $comment);
}

  print($xml->asXML());


?>
```

What I want is for it to generate an XML file that i can reference.  I'm not sure where the HTML tags are from but they are giving me an error code.

Comment: Check the raw output of the script. In your case HTML tags can be PHP warnings/notices.

Comment: In your example code you are adding a link child, but example output is img. Did you chop out the wrong code?

Comment: Also your list/explode thing can be simplified to each() to remove the need to do the middle string parsing step (and would allow a , in any of the fields)
    list($ep_id, $image, $origimg,  $actid , $date, $approve, $apptime, $fbid, $custid, $title, $comment, $admincom, $link, $lang, $video, $rate, $finalist, $brand, $day, $source) = each($values);

Comment: yes i had the wrong value in there, I was checking to see if the ('img', $img) was the reason it was not closing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: text/xml"); 
  include_once "config.php";
  mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd);
  mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("Cannot select db" . mysql_error());
  session_start();      
$query = "SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE source = 'youtube'";     
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('Entries');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $xml->startElement('entry');

      $xml->writeElement('id', $row["ep_id"]);
        $xml->writeElement('title', $row["ep_title"]);
        $xml->writeElement('thumb', '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$row["ep_youtubeid"].'/2.jpg" width="60px" /><span style="margin: -20px 0 0 5px;">'.$row["ep_title"].'</span>');
        $xml->writeElement('content', '<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="310" height="170" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$row["ep_youtubeid"].'" frameborder="0"></iframe><div style="text-align:left;color:#fff;"><strong>Title: </strong>' . $row["ep_title"].'</div><div style="text-align:left;color:#fff;"><strong>Comments: </strong>' . $row["ep_comments"].'</div><div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>');

    $xml->endElement();
};

$xml->endElement();

$xml->flush();


?>
```